# Warning if textbox is empty

Tags: vb.net-2010

I want a warning if textbox is empty when I click the button to do a math calculation.

```
Private Sub hitung_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles hitung.Click

    Dim z, iterasi, n1, n2, n3 As Single
    Dim fx0, fx1, fx2, x2, x0, x1 As Decimal

    If a.Text = Nothing Or
                  b.Text = Nothing Or
                  g.Text = Nothing Or
                  h.Text = Nothing Or
                  i.Text = Nothing Or
                  j.Text = Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("TextBox is empty", "No entry",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        With a
            .Focus()
            .SelectAll()
        End With
    End If

    x0 = (a.Text)
    x1 = (b.Text)
    n1 = (g.Text)
    n2 = (h.Text)
    n3 = (i.Text)
    iterasi = (j.Text)
```

If I leave the textbox blank and press the button, I have an error

> "Conversion from string "" to type 'Decimal' is not valid."

I changed the x0 to

```
x0 = Decimal.Parse(a.Text)
```

but the error says

> "Input string was not in a correct format."

Answer (score 0):

`Nothing` and an empty string are different things; You could use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Text)` (etc.) in place of `a.Text = Nothing` for a more resilient approach

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
  Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     If a.Text = "" Then
          MessageBox.Show("Empty TextBox", "No entry")
     End If
   End Sub
End Class
```